# How do I end one function using another function?

Tags: python, function, asynchronous, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot that has a spam feature (don't ask), and in case someone spams something I don't want them to spam, I want to have a command that can just end all spamming instead of me having to shut down my bot and then start it again in order to stop the text spam. This is what I have right now for the spam command:

```py
@client.command()
async def pls(ctx, txt, num=60):
  for i in range(num):
    await ctx.send(txt)
  await ctx.reply("spemming complete :white_check_mark:")
```

What would I need to do to stop this function/command using another function/command?

Comment: Check out `threading.Event`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects

Comment: You could make a global flag and check that every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a custom check, tethered to a member you'd like to give this capability to, in this instance, yourself. Something like:

```py
@client.command()
async def pls(ctx, word, num=60)
    me = client.get_user(#your user id here)
    def check(message):
        return message.author == me and message.content.lower() == "!stop"
    try:
        await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=num)
        await ctx.send("Yeah, this is over.")
    except:
        ####do stuff
```